# Visa for China—financial requirement?

Tags: visas, china

Looking into possibility of spending some time in China, and looked for visa requirements.

Type L looks like the only one that would work (unless I sign up for study, type X).

Three different websites listed the same requirements, but none of them said anything about financials.  I would be surprised if they don't demand evidence that the visitor has enough resources to live on.  (Also don't mention background check.)

**Is there actually no requirement for financial info?**

A search on the Chinese embassy site was fruitless—just eight press releases that didn't help.

Don't have specific plans, but it would definitely exceed a month and probably less than a year.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to the covid-19 situation, the Chinese government is [not presently issuing L (tourist) visas](http://us.china-embassy.gov.cn/eng/zytz/202206/t20220614_10702581.htm), and nobody can say with absolute certainty what procedures they will put in place when they resume doing so.

However, you are correct that in the past, no financial information has been required in order to receive a Chinese tourist visa [when applying from "rich countries"](http://losangeles.china-consulate.gov.cn/eng/visa/chinavisa/201803/t20180309_5421764.htm); as an example, I received [a Chinese visa](https://www.flickr.com/photos/mlcastle/26573669992/) in 2016 without supplying any. However, it does appear that the requirements vary somewhat by country, and e.g. Ghanaian citizens [were required to provide bank statements](http://gh.china-embassy.gov.cn/eng/lsyw/fhqz/201604/P020210828304237643193.pdf) in order to apply for visas.

Comment: There is the indirect check if you want to travel from Europe or North America to China you need to be able to afford a not really cheap plane ticket. If you can afford that, staying in China should be affordable as well.

Comment: @quarague is that a *round trip* ticket indicating you can afford to leave when the time comes?

Comment: @quarague flights into China are a huge mess right now, but under ordinary circumstances, it's almost certainly more expensive to fly from Accra to Beijing than from Los Angeles, and yet a resident of the former city must supply bank account information, while a resident of the latter need not do so.